# Jquery disable selected option in Asp.net core not working properly

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

In My project I have a table with button to add new row. In each row a select box is there when I pick an option it should be disabled in all other select boxes including the new ones. When I tried this code in here [enter link description here](https://jsfiddle.net/zre8k371/1/)
it works. But in Asp.net core it doesn't work entirely it only works for the first select box option.

This is my code in Asp.net Core, I modified it to work but still not all select box selected option updated and disabled

Why does the same code works outside visual studio and on visual studio it doesn't work the same way>

```
      <table id="empData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="UserLocation">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select id="select1" asp-for="@Model.Location" asp- 
                  items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Location>()" class="stockCode form-control" 
                  name="locations">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select id="select2" asp-for="@Model.roles" asp-items="ViewBag.Rolelist" 
                     class="form-control" name="role">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><Button onClick='deleteRow(this)' class="kx-repeatable" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<button onClick="addNewRow()" id="AddNew">Add New Row</button>
```

Jquery Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            addNewRow = function () {

                var newRow = $("#empData tbody tr").first().clone()
                $("#UserLocation").append(newRow);



            }

            deleteRow = function (element) {
                $(element).parent().parent().remove();
            }
        });


        $(document).ready(function () {

            var masterList = [];

            var selectedList = [];




                Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {

                // if the other array is a falsy value, return

                if (!array)

                    return false;



                // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 

                if (this.length != array.length)

                    return false;



                for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {

                    // Check if we have nested arrays

                    if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {

                        // recurse into the nested arrays

                        if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))

                            return false;

                    }

                    else if (this[i] != array[i]) {

                        // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != 
                           {x:20}

                        return false;

                    }

                }

                return true;

            }



            function createMasterList() {

                masterList = [];

                $('#select1\\(1\\)').children('#select1 option').each(function () {

                    masterList.push($(this).val());

                });

                masterList.shift(); //remove blank value

            }



            createMasterList(); //used to check if all dropdown values have been selected



            function updateSelectedList() {

                selectedList = [];

                var selectedValue;

                $('#empData #select1').each(function () {

                    selectedValue = $(this).find('#select1 option:selected').val();

                    if (selectedValue != "" && $.inArray(selectedValue, selectedList) == "-1") {

                        selectedList.push(selectedValue);

                    }

                });

            }



            //disable the dropdown items that have already been selected

            function disableAlreadySelected() {

                $('#select1 > option:selected').each(function () {

                    if ($.inArray(this.value, selectedList) != "-1") {

                        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");

                    } else {

                        $(this).attr("disabled", "");

                    }

                });

            }



            //If all values have been selected, don't let the user add more rows

            function hideAddButtonIfDone() {

                masterList.sort();

                selectedList.sort();

                if (masterList.equals(selectedList)) {

                    console.log("lists equal, hiding add button");

                    $('#empData #AddNew').hide();

                }

                else {

                    console.log("lists not equal, showing add button");

                    $('#empData #AddNew').show();

                }

            }



            $('#empData').on('change', '.stockCode', function () {

                setTimeout(function () {

                    updateSelectedList();

                    disableAlreadySelected();

                    hideAddButtonIfDone();

                }, 0.1);

            });



            //when a new table row is added, disable the dropdown options that have already been 
            selected

            $('#empData #AddNew').on('click', disableAlreadySelected);



            //when a table row is removed, update all dropdowns (the removed row's dropdown option 
            will be re-enabled
     
            //in remaining dropdowns

            $('#empData').on('DOMNodeRemoved', '.kx-repeatable > tr', function () {

                updateSelectedList();

                disableAlreadySelected();

                hideAddButtonIfDone();

            });



        });
```

Comment: What's the difference between the HTML you wrote in the fiddle and the HTML generated by the ASP.NET code?  If you take that exact generated HTML and create a fiddle with it, does the code still fail?  When you debug, which specific operation doesn't do what you expect?

Comment: @David the difference is in asp I'm using enums to fill the select options. While in fiddle it's a basic html select with options. In fiddle if I choose an option in the first select box of Locations. then in the other location select box it will be disabled so you can't choose it again. Now in asp code this didn't work if I select an option from the first location select box it will be disabled in other select boxes but if I choose an option from other location select boxes the option is not disabled like what happened in the first select box.

Comment: @David the user must not be able to select the same option in other location select boxes. It must be different.

Comment: If you're not familiar with how to debug code in the browser then now is a great time to start familiarizing yourself with that.  In your browser's debugging tools you can observe the actual resulting HTML generated by the server-side code and see how it differs from what you expected in your hand-written sample HTML.  You can also use the browser's script debugger to place breakpoints in your JavaScript code and step through it line by line as it executes, observing the results of each individual operation.  When you do this, your goal is to find the first operation which fails in some way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is because id is not unique,when add a new row,it will create selects with the same ids,so the element cannot be found and used correctly by id.Here is a working demo:

```
<table id="empData">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Role</th>
                <th>Action</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="UserLocation">

            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.Location" asp- 
                  items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<Location>()" class="stockCode form-control" 
                  name="locations">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select asp-for="@Model.roles" asp-items="ViewBag.Rolelist" 
                     class="form-control" name="role">
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td><Button onClick='deleteRow(this)' class="kx-repeatable" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<button onClick="addNewRow()" id="AddNew">Add New Row</button>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            addNewRow = function () {

                var newRow = $("#empData tbody tr").first().clone()
                $("#UserLocation").append(newRow);
                disableAlreadySelected();


            }

            deleteRow = function (element) {
                $(element).parent().parent().remove();
            }

            var masterList = [];

            var selectedList = [];




            Array.prototype.equals = function (array) {

                // if the other array is a falsy value, return

                if (!array)

                    return false;



                // compare lengths - can save a lot of time 

                if (this.length != array.length)

                    return false;



                for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {

                    // Check if we have nested arrays

                    if (this[i] instanceof Array && array[i] instanceof Array) {

                        // recurse into the nested arrays

                        if (!this[i].equals(array[i]))

                            return false;

                    }

                    else if (this[i] != array[i]) {

                        // Warning - two different object instances will never be equal: {x:20} != 
                        { x: 20 }

                        return false;

                    }

                }

                return true;

            }



            function createMasterList() {

                masterList = [];

                $('#select1\\(1\\)').children('#select1 option').each(function () {

                    masterList.push($(this).val());

                });

                masterList.shift(); //remove blank value

            }



            createMasterList(); //used to check if all dropdown values have been selected



            function updateSelectedList() {

                selectedList = [];

                var selectedValue;

                $('#empData .stockCode').each(function (index,element) {

                    selectedValue = $(element).find('option:selected').val();

                    if (selectedValue != "" && $.inArray(selectedValue, selectedList) == "-1") {

                        selectedList.push(selectedValue);

                    }

                });

            }



            //disable the dropdown items that have already been selected

            function disableAlreadySelected() {
                
                $('.stockCode > option').each(function (index,element) {

                    if ($.inArray(element.value, selectedList) != "-1") {

                        $(element).attr("disabled", "disabled");

                    } else {

                        $(element).removeAttr("disabled");

                    }

                });

            }



            //If all values have been selected, don't let the user add more rows

            function hideAddButtonIfDone() {

                masterList.sort();

                selectedList.sort();

                if (masterList.equals(selectedList)) {

                    console.log("lists equal, hiding add button");

                    $('#empData #AddNew').hide();

                }

                else {

                    console.log("lists not equal, showing add button");

                    $('#empData #AddNew').show();

                }

            }



            $('#empData').on('change', '.stockCode', function () {

                setTimeout(function () {

                    updateSelectedList();

                    disableAlreadySelected();

                    hideAddButtonIfDone();

                }, 0.1);

            });



            //when a new table row is added, disable the dropdown options that have already been selected

            //$('#empData #AddNew').on('click', disableAlreadySelected);



            //when a table row is removed, update all dropdowns (the removed row's dropdown option 
            //will be re - enabled

            //in remaining dropdowns

            $('#empData').on('DOMNodeRemoved', '.kx-repeatable > tr', function () {

                updateSelectedList();

                disableAlreadySelected();

                hideAddButtonIfDone();

            });



        });
```

result:
[image]

Comment: right now the item selected in one of the select box is disabled in all others but the issue it also appears disabled if I inspect the option is disabled so I can't actually use it. How can I fix this?

Comment: `<select></select>` will have a default value,for example,it shows Paris,the selected value is Paris,after `function updateSelectedList()`,the  value will be added to selectedList.Before you inspect the option,the option has already been the selected value of select.That's why  the option is disabled after `function updateSelectedList()`.

Comment: How can I possibly fix this? because right now I can't add them to my database because they are disabled .

Comment: I'm afraid not,<select></select> cannot remove it's default value.